# SenderID validation using java based email filter

Tags: java, spf, sender-id

I am using [jSPF](http://james.apache.org/jspf/index.html) to validate [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records for incoming email addresses.

Now I need to support [Sender-ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_ID) too.

Is it possible to use the same code of jSPF or with some patches I could use it for validating [Sender-ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_ID) too?

I had checked the jSPF code but they only support SPF RFC-4408 only.

I am ready to write the patch by myself in java if I could not find any existing SenderID validation library in java,

moreover I tried to read RFC 4406 and RFC 4408 to implement SenderID in java but the RFC confused me further regarding the right implementation path as it refers SPF RFC's and formatting's too.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Perhaps there are also webservices to do this.

For example: http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/default.aspx

shows if there are entries for domain xy. Perhaps you can parse and use them. But please check out if you are allowed to use this webservices.

Comment: Don't want to use webservices, will result in unnecessary delays.